# How to change background image in hover?

Tags: css, image, background, hover

The image file which I'm working with is a `.png file` created out of two identical objects in different colors (blue/orange). **The objects in the .png file are next to eachother.** What I want to do is that the background image is set to the left part of the .png (blue) and in hover to the right part (orange) of the .png. I know how it works when the objects within the .png are under eachother 
example :

```
.facebook_ico {
  background : transparent url('img/social-icons.png') bottom right no-repeat;
}

.facebook_ico:hover {
  background : transparent url('img/social-icons.png') top right no-repeat;
}
```

- but how does this work if the objects are next to each other?

To avoid any misunderstanding, I'm looking for a way to use a background image which has multiple object **next to eachother** (in this case 2). Is that possible or do I need to have them **under eachother** to be able to change them in `hover`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.facebook_ico {
  background: transparent url('img/social-icons.png') bottom left no-repeat;
}

.facebook_ico:hover {
  background-position: bottom right;
}
```

Comment: THanks but doesn't work, the background image (blue) in the left side, moves in `hover` to the right side

Comment: @Teo and is that now what you wanted?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear about that, what I try to find out is not how to use the left/right side of the div, but the left/right side of the image png.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
.facebook_ico {
  background : transparent url('img/social-icons.png') top left no-repeat; width:30px; height:30px
}

.facebook_ico:hover {
  background : transparent url('img/social-icons.png') top right no-repeat;width:30px; height:30px
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `background-position`:

```
.something {
   background-position: 0px 0px;
}

.something:hover {
   background-position: 20px 0px
}
```

Set the values to match the size of your icon.

Answer (score 1):

like said you can use

```
.facebook_ico {
  background : transparent url('img/social-icons.png') top left no-repeat;
}

.facebook_ico:hover {
  background-position : top right;
}
```

and in case its truncated its better to use pixel values to get exact background

```
.facebook_ico {
  background : transparent url('img/social-icons.png') top 0px no-repeat;
}

.facebook_ico:hover {
  background-position : top 120px;
}
```